# Does Racket offer anything for implementing a language with its own GC that could manage GPU memory?

Tags: garbage-collection, racket

I am working on [this](https://github.com/mrakgr/The-Spiral-Language) and I have some regrets with that I am going to have to do some kind of region based memory allocation scheme for GPU memory because .NET does not allow the adequate level of control over its GC.

I was too naive. I admit that it did cross my mind that just because I was on a platform with GC that I would (and should) not have to do manual memory management, nor would I need to know how the C malloc works nor how it is implemented. I want to do better than this.

What are Racket's facilities in this area?

Comment: Out of curiosity, is your Spiral a hobby project, or do you have the chance of being funded 4 to 7 years working on it full time?

Comment: I guess you could call it a hobby project, but I have nothing better to do so I am working on it full time. I do not really care about it being funded or attracting users. I have a single goal of making the ideal ML library using it. Originally I tried to make a ML library in F#, but the language simply lacked power for it. Spiral has quite enough of that, but unfortunately it is tied down to the .NET's GC which I cannot extend. There are some ways it could wrap unmanaged resources, but they won't be enough for dealing with GPU memory. I want the full GC treatment for them.

Comment: Have you published papers in some conferences? Look into [SIGPLAN](http://www.sigplan.org/)

Comment: Let me just say that I am investigating Racket's capabilities here since it is marketing itself as a PL for PLs. I do not have much experience in it apart from doing some simple exercises and reading some papers on it. Also no, I haven't published any papers nor have I written any. I fell into being a PL researcher by accident and I am hoping to do work on reinforcement learning in Spiral once I get the library done.

Comment: Consider asking this question on the racket mailing list. There are a lot of knowledgeable people on the  list, that doesn’t participate on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 2):

No. GPU processors are not like CPUs, and practically speaking don't run any GC-ed language implementation, but some very low-level code (e.g. using [OpenCL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenCL) or [CUDA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CUDA) or [OpenACC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenACC) or [SPIR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Portable_Intermediate_Representation)). They don't really have some general purpose [dynamic memory allocation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_management#DYNAMIC), and they might not even have any [virtual memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory) or [MMU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_management_unit). Their memory is generally separate.

What you could do is use some *existing* library having some [GPU compute kernels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compute_kernel) (like [TensorFlow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TensorFlow), [OpenCV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenCV), etc...) and call that library from your Racket based thing using some foreign function interface.

What you might do with *a lot of work* (probably several years) is to generate some kernel code in OpenCL or CUDA (or [SPIR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Portable_Intermediate_Representation)) -mixed with some other generated code managing that kernel code-, that is to implement a compiler from a small subset (to be painfully defined) of your Spiral language  into OpenCL or CUDA kernels. In that case, **the evil is in the details** (and the kernel code you'll generate would depend upon the particular GPU *model*). You could look into [SPOC](http://mathiasbourgoin.github.io/SPOC/) for inspiration.

> nor would I need to know how the C malloc works nor how it is implemented.

It is much worse than that. You'll need to care of a *lot* of low level details, you'll need to code stuff specific to your OS and hardware, and understanding C malloc is easier than taking care of all the GPU details (that is, generating the "right" GPU and glue code: dive into the specifications of OpenCL for more).

<sup>(I believe that it is not worth the effort -several years-  to compile your Spiral into GPU kernel code and the necessary glue code running in the CPU)</sup>

You should also read more about garbage collection, e.g. the [GC handbook](http://gchandbook.org/).

> I was too naive.

You probably still are. Your subject is harder than what you think, if you want an efficient and competitive implementation. Coding a naïve GC (or VM) is easy, but coding an efficient one is hard (requiring several years of work).

> I want to do better than this.

You'll need several years of full time work.

Comment: I am already done with the work in your last paragraph - the GPU kernels and their compilation is not the problem. The language is efficient enough to support both F# and Cuda and anything else I might want. I am not that far away from making a world class ML library in it with the exception of having a good way of managing resources that are unmanageable for me in .NET. If Racket had a good story in that regard while I would not move to it right away, I would seriously consider it. I do not see much choice here, it will have to be either Racket, or I will have to write my own VM.

Comment: You might have to write your own VM. You certainly should budget *several years* of full-time work for your goals (and it could happen that when you have finished, your work would be obsolete because GPUs would have evolved since then). Good luck, you need a lot of it!

Comment: Well, I already spent a year and most of the work on the language itself is done. Some of the stuff I've done is already obsolete because I have a GTX 970 and the newer Cuda versions have cooperative groups, but that is not the problem since it won't be too hard to rewrite the kernels once I get a new card. Really, all I am asking here is for a GC that could handle GPU memory. The things you are telling me would take several years have already been done.

Comment: Great (but is your code robust and general-purpose?). What about OpenCL and AMD GPUs? You'll then need to write your own GPU-capable GC, and that is not easy. Writing a naive GC is easy. Writing a competitive one is hard.

Comment: It is Cuda specific, but apart from that the kernels are generic to the degree that would be impossible in any other language. In fact this is the very reason why I created Spiral in the first place - having to write wrappers by hand and use text macros for things like generic map operations was hell in my previous library back in 2016.